# Does the eye image interval refresh?

Tags: human-biology, eyes

It's known the human eye takes 24 images per second. But does this refresh?
For example after sleeping.

Or will it always be the same interval?

I talk about when the eye takes the images. So it are 24 images in the second, but this second is not defined. It can start at 09:00:00.00 or 09:00:00.50. Will this change after taking a sleep?

Hope it is clear what I'm talking about.

Comment: The human eye does not take 24 images per second - this is only (approximately) what is needed for a film to look fluid - and the image we see is continuously updated and interpreted by the brain. Saturation of human perception is another thing, that is, the maximum frame rate that we can perceive, and this depends for instance on light conditions.

Comment: Related question: [What is the equivalent of shutter-speed in Human eye?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/what-is-the-equivalent-of-shutter-speed-in-human-eye)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Human eyes do not take 24 images per second. Refresh done in parallel, each pixel separately, and the rate depends on the rate of color changing.

So, the work of eye is closer to MPEG encoding than to uncompressed AVI.